# Filepath and textboxes

Tags: c#

Ok I am going to try this again. I got more information now. I understand I can not use open and save dialogs and there is no database. So I am still kinda lost cause I was shown how to do it with open and save dialogs before. I am going to put what I am suppose to do and then so far the code I have. The code I have I have to build off and add too. I will also show what I am suppose to add to it. I am just trying to find the best way to understand this cause right now I am not. I am still new and I know the last couple days people have been trying to help me understand and then I was told it wasnt with the open and save dialog. Here is what I am suppose to do.

•Add a textbox named txtFilePath <--- already have that

•Add a button next to the above textbox that says “Load” (name it appropriately)<-already have that

•Add a button that says “Save” (name it appropriately) <-- already have this

•When thebutton “Load” is clicked, read the file specified in the textbox
 (txtFilePath: Absolute path not relative) and add the objects found
 within to the listbox<--- Not understanding

•When the user clicks the “Save” button, write the selected record to
 the file specified in txtFilePath (absolute path not relative) without
 truncating the values currently inside<-- not understanding

Here is the one part of code I have:`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EditDialog newEmployeeDialog = new EditDialog();
            if (newEmployeeDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                employeeList.Items.Add(newEmployeeDialog.StaffMember);
            }
        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (employeeList.SelectedIndex == -1)
                return;

            if (MessageBox.Show("Really delete this employee",
                "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Question)
            == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                employeeList.Items.Remove(
                    employeeList.SelectedItem);
            }
        }

        private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (employeeList.SelectedIndex == -1)
                return;

            int employeeNum = employeeList.SelectedIndex;
            EditDialog newEmployeeDialog = new EditDialog();
            newEmployeeDialog.StaffMember =
                (Employee)employeeList.SelectedItem;

            if (newEmployeeDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                employeeList.Items.RemoveAt(employeeNum);
                employeeList.Items.Insert(employeeNum, newEmployeeDialog.StaffMember);
                employeeList.SelectedIndex = employeeNum;
            }
        }

        private void employeeList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (employeeList.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                Employee currentEmployee = (Employee)employeeList.SelectedItem;
                firstName.Text = currentEmployee.FirstName;
                lastName.Text = currentEmployee.LastName;
                jobTitle.Text = currentEmployee.JobTitle;
            }
            else
            {
                firstName.Text = lastName.Text = jobTitle.Text = "";
            }
        }
`
```

Now I know you can not see the button click but I do have them mark. I know when you use open and save how it works. How I can go about this? I would use stream writer right.I understand that the user will type the path into the textbox and when the user hits load, it will load the file that they are specified. Now I am just trying to understand a code to be able to word this right.

would it be something like this:

```
String filePath = this.txtFilePath.Text;
```

since I need to name the textbox txtFilePath. I know some of you might say this is simple but when you are first learning it don't seem that simple. I have been trying something to help me understand since I do my college from home. Thank you for reading hoping to hear from you guys.

Update: Would it be something like this

Reading a file

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(C:\\")
txtFilePath.Text = my reader.read to end();
myReader.Close();
}
```

then there is writing a file

```
{
StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\test.txt", true);
            myWriter.Write("Some text");
            myWriter.WriteLine("Write a line");
            myWriter.WriteLine("Line 2");
            myWriter.Close();
}
```

If this is correct then I have to get it where if the file is not there for the notepad to pop up so they can add it then they can save it without deleting anything out the file or files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the file contains a list of employee names, you should be able to load them into your listbox using something like this:

```
var filepath = txtFilePath.Text;
if (File.Exists(filepath))
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
    foreach (var line in lines)
        employeeList.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Then assuming you want to add a new employee name to the file that the user just entered into the listbox:

```
var filepath = txtFilePath.Text;
if (File.Exists(filepath))
    using (var sw = File.AppendText(filepath)) 
        sw.WriteLine((string)employeeList.Text);
else
    using (var sw = File.CreateText(filepath)) 
        sw.WriteLine((string)employeeList.Text);
```

This hasn't been tested, but it should work nearly as-is...

Comment: That is what I am working on is the code itself so the file will be loaded into the listbox. I am so I am trying to understand so I can write the code.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use the opendialog but I am not allowed to use it. And the save one I think it is to save the employeeslist that will allow you to save each person.

Comment: This is what he told me user will type path into the textbox and when they hit load, you have to load the file they specified. And it has to be absolute and if they type in something like C:\text.txt and its not there then it will create one in a blank document.It will also take the name in file and add it to the list box.

Comment: More less it will be doing something of making a notepad but only using the load and save button but then the file with the names in it will be placed in the employees list box. If I am understanding it right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10445/discussion-between-shan-and-grant-winney)